# SSH login failed for only one user

Tags: ssh, authentication

I have a few users using ssh ppk to authenticate, which used to work smoothly untli recently. Now for all the users everything is fine, except for one.
When trying to authenticate, we get *no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey)*.

I tried all the combinations of permissions for both /home/username/.ssh (now set as drwxr-xr-x) and for /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys (now set as -rw-------). The owner of both the folder and the file is root.

I tried generating a new public/private key, adding the new public one to the authorized_keys and connecting with the new one - doesn't work.
There is nothing in /var/log/auth.log but in journalctl i can see only this:

*Apr 14 17:37:59 ip-10-0-0-239 sshd[22506]: error: Received disconnect from xx.172.218.xx port 61682:14: No authentication methods available [preauth]

Apr 14 17:37:59 ip-10-0-0-239 sshd[22506]: Disconnected from xx.172.218.xx port 61682 [preauth]*

any ideas?

Comment: *"The owner of both the folder and the file is root."* that sounds like a problem, right there

Comment: Please let us know the OS version of the server and of the client. For example newer Ubuntu 20.04 client won't connect to older RedHat /Centos 5 machines. 
What is the error on the client side? Please try running ssh client with verbose option `ssh -v destination_server_hostname` thus you will also see what private SSH keys are loaded

Comment: @steeldriver I was sure I was attempting it before with the target user as owner... apparently I didn't, because I changed the owner and it works now!

Comment: The SSH documents specify the ownership and permission requirements for the `.ssh` directory and its contents. When they're wrong (`root`:`root`) `.ssh` ignores the directory as if it didn't exist. Read `man -k ssh`.